# LC-3 Decimal Converter

Tags: subroutine, lc3

I am required to make a program that converts the user input decimal number (can be negative and greater than 9) into a 16 bit binary number or exit when they press X. We have to do so using masks and branches, but I believe we also have to use subroutines and I do not understand how to do so. I understand the use of masks and branches, but I can only get it to work with decimals between 0-9, beyond this I cannot make it work. If anyone has pointers it would be great.

Comment: There are a lot of elements that need to be implemented for a project like this. I would recommend breaking up these tasks into smaller programs where you can test the code for each. For example make a program that can convert decimal values into binary values, another that checks user input, and another that tests the use of subroutines. Once you have some sample code for those concepts post them here and as specific questions about the problems you're having.

Comment: We want to help you with this project but we need something to work with, because I don't want to code this entire project and post it here for you to simply copy.

Comment: Understandable, not trying to copy any code, I'll try to get a little farther and get some working code to post that someone can help with.